# Complex SQL to LINQ to populate Grid (Count items year by month) (MVC, EF Code First)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, t-sql

I have a grid that I want to fill with the following:

It is tracking tickets that have been open each month for the last year. The grid is filtered by priority so I have a something like this:

```
| Mon | Critical | High | Tot |
| Jan |    5     |  2   |  7  |
| Feb |    2     |  3   |  5  |
```

This is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    MONTH(CreateDate),
    DATENAME(MONTH,m.CreateDate) AS 'Month',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (m.PriorityId = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Critical',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (m.PriorityId = 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'High',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (m.PriorityId = 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Normal',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (m.PriorityId = 4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Low',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (m.PriorityId = 5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Not Ready',
    Count(m.Id) AS Total
FROM
    [projects].[dbo].[tblMaintenanceTicket] m
INNER JOIN
    [projects].[dbo].[tblPriority] p
ON
    p.Id = m.PriorityId
WHERE
    StatusId = 1
    AND YEAR(CreateDate) = year(getdate())
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(CreateDate),
    DATENAME(MONTH,m.CreateDate)
ORDER BY
    MONTH(CreateDate)
```

I am looking to convert this in VB LINQ but I am not sure this is the best method. I am also thinking calling a stored procedure, but I want to stay out of the DB really. I am using MVC 3 with the repository pattern, so calling my code is something like this output for JSON:

```
Dim tickets = ticketRepo.GetAll().Include(Function(p) p.Priority).ToArray()
```

Any assistance?

Comment: Can you provide fully qualified names in your SQL?

Comment: I have added the fqn to the database tables, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: What table is the StatusId in?

Comment: @Chuck: That helps a bit, but I also mean for the column references in the actual query. Is your `WHERE` clause supposed to read: `WHERE m.StatusId = 1` or `WHERE p.StatusId = 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do, currently making the assumption that the StatusId is in the tblMaintenanceTicket table.

Visual Basic:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

    Dim rand As New Random
    Dim list As New List(Of tblMaintenanceTicket)
    For count = 1 To 100

      Dim newTicket As New tblMaintenanceTicket

      newTicket.CreateDate = Now.AddDays(rand.Next(0, 365) * -1)
      newTicket.PriorityId = rand.Next(1, 6)
      newTicket.StatusId = 1

      list.Add(newTicket)

    Next

    Dim results = From ticket In list _
                  Where ticket.StatusId = 1 And ticket.CreateDate.Year = Now.Year _
                  Group ticket By ticket.CreateDate.Month Into Group _
                  Select New TicketResults With { _
                    .Month = Month,
                    .Critical = Group.Count(Function(t) t.PriorityId = 1),
                    .High = Group.Count(Function(t) t.PriorityId = 2),
                    .Normal = Group.Count(Function(t) t.PriorityId = 3),
                    .Low = Group.Count(Function(t) t.PriorityId = 4),
                    .NotReady = Group.Count(Function(t) t.PriorityId = 5)
                  }


    End Sub

  Public Class tblMaintenanceTicket

    Public CreateDate As Date
    Public PriorityId As Integer
    Public StatusId As Integer

  End Class

  Public Class TicketResults

    Public Month As Integer
    Public Critical As Integer
    Public High As Integer
    Public Normal As Integer
    Public Low As Integer
    Public NotReady As Integer

  End Class

End Module
```

C#:

```
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      //Generate some random data
      var list = new List<tblMaintenanceTicket>();    
      var rand = new Random();    
      for (var count = 0; count < 100; ++count)
      {
        var newTicket = new tblMaintenanceTicket();

        newTicket.CreateDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(rand.Next(0, 365)* -1);
        newTicket.PriorityId = rand.Next(1, 6);
        newTicket.StatusId = 1;

        list.Add(newTicket);
      }


      var results = from ticket in list
                    where ticket.StatusId == 1 && ticket.CreateDate.Year == DateTime.UtcNow.Year
                    group ticket by ticket.CreateDate.Month into months
                    select new TicketResults
                    {
                      Month = months.Key,
                      Critical = months.Count(m => m.PriorityId == 1),
                      High = months.Count(m => m.PriorityId == 2),
                      Normal = months.Count(m => m.PriorityId == 3),
                      Low = months.Count(m => m.PriorityId == 4),
                      NotReady = months.Count(m => m.PriorityId == 5)
                    };

      System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }
  }

  public class TicketResults
  {
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Critical { get; set; }
    public int High { get; set; }
    public int Normal { get; set; }
    public int Low { get; set; }
    public int NotReady { get; set; }
  }

  public class tblMaintenanceTicket
  {
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public int PriorityId { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
  }
```